# How to add preference of Custom Input method to Android Settings app?

Tags: android, settings, preferences, android-softkeyboard

Recently I've started to develop Android Soft Keyboard and got some problem with preferences.

How to add a preferences  to Android setting app? I've searched almost all the source code of AnySoftKeyboard, but haven't found anything what would add them to Settings app.

I'm placing a link to show what I meant: http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/wiki/Settings

(first picture from begin)

Thank you

P.S. Sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found it myself:

in XML of input method you need to put **android:settingsActivity** tag with link to your PreferenceActivity class:
[Example](http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/source/browse/trunk/project/res/xml/method.xml)

Comment: can you past the code here? think is very hard to get the code from

Comment: You should really have posted the code rather than just a link somewhere, because links expire or get moved without proper care taken to re-route them to the new destination.  Please post code and I'll delete my comment and possibly upvote your answer...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example: set android:settingsActivity in your input-method xml declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<input-method
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:settingsActivity="com.justes.yogabook.holo_keyboard.wrapper.SettingsActivity">
    <subtype
        android:label="@string/yogabook_holo_keyboard_subtype_label"
        android:imeSubtypeLocale="en_US"
        android:imeSubtypeMode="keyboard" />
</input-method>
```