# How to add preference in setting in android

Tags: android

Currently I am busy with designing keyboard maximum functionality of the keyboard has been completed at that time i am facing a problem regard setting of this key board like Speed of typing, spell checking, suggestion box and other think i know this is control by Preference.
But i don't know about how to add preference in android setting.
Means user control this keyboard setting by these following step.

Settings >Language and Keyboard  >My Keyboard name > Setting of this Keyboard.

Can any one told me hoe can it possible thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own custom firmware.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524110/how-to-add-preference-of-custom-input-method-to-android-settings-app) and answer covers what you want to do?