# How to add my keyboard settings activity on default android settings

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, preferenceactivity

I am working on creating my own keyboard and it has `Settings Activity`. Now I want settings should be shown in default `keyboard` setting.
found some where that settings activity should extend `PreferenceActivity` but still no luck with that.

Is there any flags in `Manifest.xml`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manage by myself...

in method.xml set a flag `android:settingsActivity="your settings activity"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- The attributes in this XML file provide configuration information -->
<!-- for the Search Manager. -->

<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:settingsActivity="com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard.MainSettings"/>
```

[found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528859/730600 [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528859/730600)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a manifest file which could help you out in this.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard" android:versionName="v1.20" android:versionCode="1020">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />

    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="11" android:minSdkVersion="8"></uses-sdk>

    <application android:label="@string/english_ime_name"
            android:backupAgent="LatinIMEBackupAgent"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:killAfterRestore="false" android:icon="@drawable/icon">

        <service android:name="LatinIME"
                android:label="@string/english_ime_name"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method" />
        </service>

        <activity android:name="Main" android:label="Hacker's Keyboard">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="LatinIMESettings" android:label="@string/english_ime_settings">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="LatinIMEDebugSettings" android:label="@string/english_ime_debug_settings">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="InputLanguageSelection"
                android:label="@string/language_selection_title">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <action android:name="org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard.INPUT_LANGUAGE_SELECTION"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```